# Spectrogram of complex exponential functions in Mathematica 9

Tags: version-9, signal-processing

How can the v9.0 built-in `Spectrogram[list, n, d]` function be modified to accept complex exponential functions?

The V8.0.4 code that produces the result I'm looking for follows.  How do I adapt v9.0 to do the same thing?

```
*************
(* Spectrogram of complex exponentials using MMA_ 8.0.4 *)
Clear[se, \
fs, \[CapitalDelta]T, n]; se[amp_, f_] := amp*Exp[2 \[Pi] I f t]
fs = 100 ; \[CapitalDelta]T = 130 ; \[CapitalDelta]t = N[1/fs]; n = 
 fs*\[CapitalDelta]T; \[CapitalDelta]f = 
 N[1/(2 \[CapitalDelta]T)] ; fmax = N[1/(2 \[CapitalDelta]t)];
Clear[f1, f2, f3]; f1 = 10; f2 = 20; f3 = -13; 
cs1 = N[Table[
   se[1, f1] , {t, 0, \[CapitalDelta]T, \[CapitalDelta]t}] ]; cs1 = 
 Most[cs1];
cs2 = N[Table[
   se[1, f2] , {t, 0, \[CapitalDelta]T, \[CapitalDelta]t}] ]; cs2 = 
 Most[cs2];
cs3 = N[Table[
   se[1, f3] , {t, 0, \[CapitalDelta]T, \[CapitalDelta]t}] ]; cs3 = 
 Most[cs3];
w1 = Table[
  1, {4000}];  Length[w1]; (* rectangular window *)
Length[cs1] ;
w1ls = ArrayPad[w1, {0, Length[cs1] - Length[w1]} ]; Length[w1ls] ;
wcs1 = w1ls*cs1; Length[wcs1];
ListLinePlot[Re[wcs1], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> 250];
w2 = Table[1, {4000}]; Length[w2];
Length[cs2];
w2ls = ArrayPad[
  w2, {Length[w1] + 1 , ( 
    Length[cs2] - Length[w1] - 1 - Length[w2])  }]; Length[w2ls];
wcs2 = w2ls*cs2; Length[wcs2];
ListLinePlot[Re[wcs2], Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Green, ImageSize -> 250];
w3 = Table[1, {5000}]; Length[w3];
Length[cs3] ;
w3ls = ArrayPad[
  w3, { (Length[w1] + 1 + Length[w2] + 1), ( 
    Length[cs3] - Length[w1] - Length[w2] - 1 - Length[w3] - 
     1 )}];  Length[w3ls];
wcs3 = w3ls*cs3; Length[wcs3];
(********)
Clear[in]; in = 
 wcs1 + wcs2 + 
  wcs3 ;(* Composite Complex Signal *)
(********)
(* Set up STFT \
parameters *)
ns = 100 ;(*specify # samples/segment*)
insegs = 
 Partition[in, ns, 1, {1, 1}];
finsegs = 
  Chop[Fourier[#, FourierParameters -> {-1, -1}] ] & /@ insegs; 
ffinsegs = Abs[finsegs]^2;
rffinsegs = RotateRight[#, (ns/2) - 1] & /@ ffinsegs; 
p = ArrayPlot[Transpose[rffinsegs], DataReversed -> True,
  FrameTicks -> 
   {   { { { 
       0, - 5*fmax/5}, {ns*(1/10), -4*fmax/5}, {ns*(2/10), -3*fmax/5},
       {ns*(3/10), -2*fmax/5}, {ns*(4/10), -1*fmax/5},
      {ns*(5/10), 0}, {ns*(6/10), fmax/5}, {ns*(7/10), 
       2*fmax/5}, {ns*(8/10), 3*fmax/5 }, {ns*(9/10), 
       4*fmax/5}, {ns*(10/10), 5*fmax/5 "Hz"} }, None } ,
      { {{1000, 10}, {2000, 20}, {3000, 30}, {4000, 40}, {5000, 
       50}, {6000, 60}, {7000, 70}, {8000, 80}, {9000, 90}, {10000, 
       100}, {11000, 110}, {12000, 120}, {13000, 130 "sec"} }, 
     None }  },
   AspectRatio -> 1/3 , ImageSize -> 650 , 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontWeight -> Bold, 12}]

(* MMA_ 9.0: Using built-in command < Spectrogram[list,n,d] > *)

Spectrogram[in, 100, 1]
Spectrogram[Re[in], 100, 1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you try this?

```
Unprotect[Evaluate@Spectrogram];
PrependTo[DownValues@Spectrogram, 
  HoldPattern@
    Spectrogram[l : {___, _Complex, ___}, 
     n : (_Integer | Automatic) : Automatic, 
     m : (_Integer | Automatic) : Automatic, OptionsPattern[]] :> 
   Spectrogram[Re@InverseFourier@PadRight[Fourier@l, 2 Length@l, 0`], 
    If[n === Automatic, ## &[], 2 n], 
    If[m === Automatic, ## &[], 2 m], 
    SampleRate :> 
     If[OptionValue[SampleRate] === Automatic, Automatic, 
      2 OptionValue[SampleRate]]]];
Protect[Spectrogram];
```

So if

```
Spectrogram[Table[Cos[ i/4 + (i/20)^2], {i, 2000}], SampleRate -> 10]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

then

```
Spectrogram[Table[Cos[ i/4 + (i/20)^2], {i, 2000}] + 0.01 I, 
 SampleRate -> 10]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I honestly couldn't test it much or try your code but I figure you want it to work like Matlab's, where if complex, the full spectrum is shown. I'll be back in some minutes and delete this if it doesn't work as intended

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I find that using your mod results in a disparity between the window size (that seems to be locked at 2) and the desired partition size, 100 in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry about that @stqnt. I double the points so probably `n`  and `d` should be doubled too? Check it, I'll edit now